# Custom filtering does not work as expected

Tags: typescript

I have created a function which filters an array of data by one or more properties.

It looks like this:

```
public filtered = createTransformer((filter: { [key: string]: string }): EntityType[] => {
    let array = this.entities

    Object.keys(filter).forEach(key => {
        array = array.filter(entity => {
            const propertyString = (this.propertyAccessor(entity, key) || '').toString().trim().toLowerCase()
            const filterString = filter[key].trim().toLowerCase()

            return propertyString.includes(filterString)
        })
    })

    return array
})
```

Then I have a test suite:

```
describe('filter tests', () => {
    it('should filter one column', async () => {
        await setEntities([
            {id: 0, love: 5, isSuper: false},
            {id: 1, love: 1, isSuper: true}
        ])

        const store = new TestEntityStore()
        await store.fetchAll()

        expect(
            store.getEntity(0)
        ).toBeDefined()

        const filter = {
            'id': '0'
        }

        expect(
            store.filtered(filter).length
        ).toEqual(
            store.entities.filter(x => x.id == 0).length
        )
    })
})
```

The result

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
   1
Received:
   0
```

I have no idea what might have gone wrong. I am 100% sure that `propertyAccessor` and `createTransformer` are not the issue.

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is presumably that `0 || ""` is `""`, not `0`.  The number `0` is  [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), so you are being careless with your check here:

```
(this.propertyAccessor(entity, key) || '')
```

This works for the `{id: 1}` case, but the `{id: 0}` case is handled incorrectly.  Assuming you are only looking to eliminate `undefined` or `null` values and not all falsy ones, you might want a helper function like:

```
function saferOr<T, U>(t: T | null | undefined, deflt: U): T | U {
  return (typeof t === 'undefined' || t === null) ? deflt : t;
}
```

and then use it instead of `||`:

```
const propertyString = saferOr(this.propertyAccessor(entity, key), '').
  toString().trim().toLowerCase();
```

---

By the way, I'm not some magical JavaScript wizard who just glanced at your code and solemnly intoned "*Unexpectedly Falsy*".  I had to add `console.log()` statements to the code, check for weird results, and notice that `console.log(propertyString)` was spitting out `""` instead of the expected `0`.  I strongly recommend that you try to log and/or step through your code with a debugger when you run into issues like this.  Stack Overflow is great, and you should definitely ask questions if you need help, but if you want to diagnose and fix something, doing it yourself is usually faster and more reliable than trying to produce a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then waiting for someone else to hopefully understand and then answer it correctly.

---

Hope that helped. Happy coding!

Comment: Passes :) Thank you!